# Can I trigger Accept & Buy button of Google Play programatically?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-play-services

I downloaded v3 sample project for In-app billing from android developer and started playing with it. It works fine.
Can I do a PerformClick() without clicking Accept & Buy button?

Specifically for people with low vision.

[image]

Comment: This dialog exists for the user to confirm the purchase. Even if it might be possible, I think you should let the user decide if he wants to buy or not.

Comment: Is there any work around for this? Because I want to enable this for my app that is going to be used by blinds.

Comment: I already said so: Don't do that, even if you find a way. Would you like to have an application which spends arbitrary amounts on your credit card without your approval? That's what that dialog is for. If you manage to override it, that will be questionable from the legal side as well.

Comment: Its for blinds, so I wanted to add a own button which is easily accessible for them and give them a voice feedback using tts to give info. Is there any way to link that button to own button or any work around?

Comment: Blind users are perfectly capable of navigating to that button, using the same techniques they use every day with their Android device (arrow keys/trackball, "explore by touch", TalkBack, etc.). "Is there any way to link that button to own button or any work around?" -- fortunately, no.

Answer (score 4):

You cant do that. `Google API` will take care of that. You will get the response after the financial transaction completed(if the apptype is paid) as nonce object. Based on response, you have to handle application status.

Check the App Purchase Flow [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html#checkout)

Comment: Is there any work around for this? Because I want to enable this for my app that is going to be used by blinds.

Comment: @TheAndroDev There is no workaround to link `ACCEPT/BUY` button to our application  button. Please see the above comment of CommonsWare for the question. Blind users can be able to navigate to the `ACCEPT/BUY` button using arrow keys/trackball, TalkBack....